# Error installing faiss-cpu - No module named 'swig'

Tags: python, pip, swig, langchain, faiss

I'm trying to install faiss-cpu via pip (`pip install faiss-cpu`) and get the following error:

```
  × Building wheel for faiss-cpu (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [12 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      building 'faiss._swigfaiss' extension
      swigging faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss.i to faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss_wrap.cpp
      swig -python -c++ -Doverride= -I/usr/local/include -Ifaiss -doxygen -module swigfaiss -o faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss_wrap.cpp faiss/faiss/python/swigfaiss.i
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/Users/me/langchain/venv/bin/swig", line 5, in <module>
          from swig import swig
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'swig'
      error: command '/Users/me/langchain/venv/bin/swig' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
```

I've searched around and tried various solutions but nothing has worked.

I have the following setup:

```
Python 3.12.1
pip 23.3.2
SWIG Version 4.1.1
Python swig package (via pip): 4.1.1.post1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`faiss-cpu` is not available in `python-3.12`. According to [their page on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/faiss-cpu/) it's available from `python-3.7` to `python-3.11`. You need to downgrade your python in order to install `faiss-cpu` in your system. Now you can either remove `python-3.12` and install `python-3.10` on your system. Or use conda to create a virtual env with `python-3.10` like following:

```
conda create -n myenv python=3.10
```

then to activate:

```
conda activate myenv
```

now install `faiss-cpu`:

```
pip install faiss-cpu
```

Comment: sorry,, that's a typo. I meant `python-3.7`. I will fix it

Comment: Thanks for the info. I came back here to give an update, I got it working by downgrading to 3.11.

Comment: Nice to hear that. yeah, as I mentioned, you can use anything from `python3.7` to `python3.11`. Though I would advice to use `python3.10` as this is the most stable widely supported by all most all libraries right now

Comment: Thank you for this information! It works! [Here](https://github.com/facebookresearch/faiss/blob/main/INSTALL.md) is a more direct link to the installation information. They also recommend `python3.10` but it works for me on `python3.11`!